# Where to find docs for some methods of an array?

Tags: ruby, api

In `irb` I make

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
#=> [1, 2, 3]
a.class
#=> Array
a.methods.sort
#=> [:!, :!=, ..., :inject, ...]
```

and get that `a` has a method `inject`, but in http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html I can't find documentation about `inject`. Why? Is it a bug in the Ruby API?

And where do I find documentation about Array's instance method `inject`?

Comment: when you are a novice and find something that looks like a bug, 99.9999% of the time it isn't...

Comment: You are right! I'll be cautious next time...

Comment: @tokland that's a very good principle in general, but IIRC some private methods aren't currently displayed on ruby-doc.org even though they're used in normal Ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) is defined in [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html), [`Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html) includes that module:

```
Array.included_modules
#=> [Enumerable, Kernel]
```

The API lists included modules below the method list.

BTW, you can inspect a method to find its origin:

```
Array.instance_method(:inject)
#=> #<UnboundMethod: Array(Enumerable)#inject>
#                      ↑        ↑
#                    Class    Module
```

Comment: Very nice interpretations... Liked it `Array.instance_method(:inject)`.. I was going to give it..but you did..so I wouldn't... :)

Comment: Last question: how know, where include any class method (::instance_method for example). I make `Array.public_class_method(:instance_method)
 => Array` but Array has not ::instance method method. I also see in Kernel and Enumerable Modules - they also has not ::instance_method method...

Comment: @igor_rb To find `instance_method`'s origin, use `Array.method(:instance_method)`, it returns `#<Method: Class(Module)#instance_method>`, so it's [`Module#instance_method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_method)

Comment: The modules included in a class are also listed in the right sidebar on Ruby Doc.

Comment: @Stefan Hm, but how Array include module `Module` ? Reading API I see that `Array` has parent `Object` and include module `Enumerable`. But `Object` and his parent `BasicObject` does not include module `Module`, `Kernel` module, included by `Object` also does not include module `Module` and finally `Enumerable` module does not include module `Module`. How ?

Comment: @igor_rb that's a bit tricky: [`Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html) is a [`Class`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Class.html) and [`Module`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html) is the parent of `Class`. Don't hesitate to post a separate question regarding Ruby's class hierarchy.